# Marking mails as read from maildrop script

Tags: linux, email, maildir, qmail, maildrop

I use a maildrop script to sort my mails directly on the mail server into folders and I would like it to mark certain unnecessary mails as read.

Unfortunately maildrop does not seem to have a command for that.

Right now I use this line to rename the newest mail of the qmail Maildir folder to a `2,s` read status:

```
 `ls -t "$MAILDIR/.0 Spamfilter.catchall/new" | head -1 | xargs -I {} mv "$MAILDIR/.0 Spamfilter.catchall/new/{}" "$MAILDIR/.0 Spamfilter.catchall/cur/{}:2,S"`
```

However, this sometimes fails and the mail remains unread. I guess there is a race condition, when another mails arrives, before the mv has been executed.

Comment: Have you tried to set `FLAGS` variable in maildropfilter? http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/maildropfilter.html

Comment: no, i did not rtfm, just followed a tutorial

Comment: Now I tried `FLAGS="S"` before `to`, but it does not seem to do anything

Comment: Omg, on the server they have maildrop 2.5.5. FLAGS was added in maildrop 2.8.4

Answer (score 0):

This before the `to` does the thing:

```
  FLAGS="S"
```

---

However, the tricky part  is to install >=2.8.4 on shared hosting without root rights.  I did it like this: Download "courier-unicode-2.0.tar.bz2" and "maildrop-2.9.2.tar.bz2" from courier-mta.org:

```
cd courier-unicode-2.0/
./configure  --prefix=/home/user/
make
make install

cd ../maildrop-2.9.2
export CPPFLAGS=-I/home/user/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/lib/
./configure  --prefix=/home/user
make
make install
```

and then changed the .qmail files to `|/home/user/bin/maildrop`